# extract a particular value from an xml document in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

my xml document looks like this

```
<contrib-group>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" xlink:type="simple">
           <string-name>
              <given-names>Anagha K.</given-names>
              <x xml:space="preserve"> </x>
              <surname>Matapurkar</surname>
           </string-name>
           <x xml:space="preserve"/>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" xlink:type="simple">
           <string-name>
              <given-names>Milind G.</given-names>
              <x xml:space="preserve"> </x>
              <surname>Watve</surname>
           </string-name>
           <x xml:space="preserve"/>
        </contrib>
        <aff id="aff_1">Life Research Foundation, 10 Pranav, 1000/6‐c, Navi Peth, Pune 411 030, India</aff>
        <x xml:space="preserve"/>
     </contrib-group>
```

i have multiple xml files each has the same structure
and i have figured out to run the code in a loop for all.

i want to extract the affiliation info from each file

i have written write an xpath expression like this in R in a function
which i loop over all the files using ldply

the libraries i used are XML, plyr

```
doc <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(tempdoc,"//aff"))
```

where tempdoc is the parsed xml document

i get an error of duplicate subscripts for columns.

Is the xpath expression wrong please help ? or can some give me an correction for the xpath syntax in the above r code line?

Comment: Which library you are using here @Preet ?

Comment: XML and plyr  i guess i am writing the xpath expression wrong. could you please check that

Comment: The XML snippet you provide is too small to understand the data structure. Is it possible for you to provide at least two `<contrib-group> ... </contrib-group>`?

Comment: @PierreGramme please check the question i have edited it

Comment: Thanks. But I can't reproduce: this example runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

With `xml2` package:

```
library(xml2)
xml_as_list <- as_list(read_xml("theFile.xml"))
xml_as_list[["contrib-group"]][["aff"]][[1]]
```

gives:

```
"Life Research Foundation, 10 Pranav, 1000/6‐c, Navi Peth, Pune 411 030, India"
```